# .htaccess redirect from old Joomla to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

im in trouble with redirect from my old Joomla to newer Wordpress site.
Website site is for example www.thatsme.cz, but when i want to load this old URL from Joomla

```
http://thatsme.cz/bydleni-a-zahrada/756-jak-poznat-zkusenou-firmu
```

Wordpress shows me 404 error, how can i redirect it so new URL will be

```
http://thatsme.cz/jak-poznat-zkusenou-firmu
```

I want to redirect more sites, so its little bit harder, i need just to remove category (bydleni-a-zahrada) and first numbers after "/" with "-".
That is all

EDIT:
My .htaccess file looks this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as your very first rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[^/]+/\d+-(.+)$ /$1
```

Comment: Looks like not working, i have inserted it right under line RewriteBase /

Comment: Use it as very first line in .htaccess. It works fine on my Apache and redirects `http://localhost/bydleni-a-zahrada/756-jak-poznat-zkusenou-firmu` to `http://localhost/jak-poznat-zkusenou-firmu`

Comment: I have inserted it before # BEGIN WordPress     but problem is same :-(

Comment: Oh, i have to insert it also to the main .htaccess above this one... (Im on shared hosting) and now IT WORKS! Big thank you! :)